# How did "the works" come to mean "everything"?

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology of "the works" meaning "everything", as in "a pizza with the works"?

Comment: Please provide a minimum of research (as required by the site standards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is from AmE slang:

From American Heritage Dictionary:

***[the works](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+works)***

> Everything, the full range of possibilities, as in He ordered a pizza with the works, or All right, tell me, give me the works on it. *This usage derives from works in the sense of "a complete set of parts for a machine or mechanism." [Colloquial; late 1800s]*

From Green’s Dictionary of Slang

***[the works:](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/b2yyqzi)***

> 1899–1900 [US]    C.L. Cullen Tales of the Ex-Tanks 133: *Costumes, street apparel, and the whole works for the presentation of ‘Shakespearian repertoire.’.*

> 1906  [US]    C. M’Govern Sarjint Larry an’ Frinds 24: Oi [...] *had de whole works clamped tight around his head.*

Comment: These are nothing more than usage examples.  The actual answer to the question is given in the @niamulbengali answer.

Answer (score 0):

'work' is a word with multiple meanings. one of the meanings is a piece of work like a piece of work of Tolstoy and the many pieces of work are called 'the works' like the collected/complete works of Tolstoy. So collected ones, everything.

Comment: Your answer is not really relevant. You must do some research before answering

Comment: @fev yes, I agree with you, but I just lightly wanted to answer with no effort, just to easily understand and accept something as 'work' has really multiple meanings. Water is water, sometimes if the word is not difficult and has no prefix, suffix or root, it is the word itself which people use as it is. Thank you for your advice though.

Comment: Ok, when you gain a bit more reputation, make sure you post such "light answers" as comments.

Comment: I've got it and thanks for your kind advice again.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, "works" meant "all the parts of a machine"; it was often used as "the works":

> Works—the parts of a machine, especially those that move
>
> *If you take the back off this clock, you can see its/the works.*
>
> — [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/work?q=the+works)

According to [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/the--works), "the works" is a modified version of "works" that was promoted from mechanic lingo:

> This usage derives from works in the sense of “a complete set of parts for a machine or mechanism.” [Colloquial; late 1800s]

Thanks to mechanics, you can say,

> I want a pizza with the works.

Comment: This is a bit of a stretch...

Comment: There are a number of phrases like *gum up the works* and *give him the works* (violent) from around that same time period, and https://www.phrases.com/phrase/gum-up-the-works_44732 attributes it to the large scale machines being built around that time, so I think while it sounds strange, dictionary.com may be right.

Comment: It's not a stretch in any way, it is the correct answer; no more of a stretch than the (very numerous) phrases derived from card gambling in the 1800s.

Comment: An outstanding point, @AlannaRose ! Good one!

Comment: The etymology from Dictionary.com is less than definitive, and does not connect the dots. This answer does not connect the dots. That makes it a stretch.